# 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

While traversing a graph in Python, a I'm receiving this error:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Here is my code:

```
def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath: return newpath
    return None
```

The code aims to find the paths from one node to others. Code source: http://cs.mwsu.edu/~terry/courses/4883/lectures/graphs.html

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['has\_key()' or 'in'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/has-key-or-in)

Answer (score 320):

`has_key` was removed in Python 3. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins):

> - Removed `dict.has_key()` – use the `in` operator instead.

Here's an example:

```
if start not in graph:
    return None
```

Comment: I think `key not in d.keys()` is probably *much* slower, too, since `key not in d` should be O(1) lookup and I believe `keys` produces a list, which is O(n) lookup (not to mention taking extra space in memory). I could be wrong about that though -- it might still be hashed lookup

Comment: @AdamSmith not in Python 3, `d.keys()` is a view that implements most of the set interface.

Comment: It removed... but why ? Since it make python 2 port to python 3 more work to do.

Comment: @林果皞: The whole point of a new major version is that the developers can introduce improvements which may include breaking changes instead of having to support old features as the language matures. This is always a risk which must be considered before upgrading to a new major version. In this case, `in` is shorter and more Pythonic, as well as being consistent with other collections in the language.

Answer (score 67):

In python3, `has_key(key)` is replaced by `__contains__(key)`

Tested in python3.7:

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
print(a.__contains__('a'))
```

Comment: I think this is the right and easier way to do, Thank you for the answer

Comment: No, no, no... the `__contains__()` method is how you *implement* a containment test in a user-defined class, the `in` operator is how you actually *use* that test.  About the only time you should ever explicitly call a double-underscored "magic" method is in a subclass method, as part of calling the superclass implementation.

Answer (score 31):

**has_key** has been deprecated in **Python 3.0**.
Alternatively you can use **'in'**

```
graph={'A':['B','C'],
   'B':['C','D']}

print('A' in graph)
>> True

print('E' in graph)
>> False
```

Answer (score 9):

I think it is considered "more pythonic" to just use `in` when determining if a key already exists, as in

```
if start not in graph:
    return None
```

Comment: I'm not sure, according to The Zen of Python(PEP 20): "Explicit is better than implicit".

I think that if you use the `in` keyword, your intention might not be clear enough
what does `if start not in graph:` means?
may be `graph` is a list and it checks if there is no such string in the list?
On the other hand, if you use syntax like `has_key` (now deprecated) or at least `in graph.keys()` it is more clear that `graph` is a `dict`

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
if start not in graph:
```

For more info see [ProgrammerSought](https://www.programmersought.com/article/91191911579/)

Answer (score 4):

The whole code in the document will be:

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
             'B': ['C', 'D'],
             'C': ['D'],
             'D': ['C'],
             'E': ['F'],
             'F': ['C']}
def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return path
        if start not in graph:
            return None
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
                if newpath: return newpath
        return None
```

After writing it, save the document and press F 5

After that, the code you will run in the Python IDLE shell will be:

find_path(graph, 'A','D')

The answer you should receive in IDLE is

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: Can you please explain it ?specifically the recursion portion.