# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key' error with Highcharts

Tags: python, python-3.9, quasar, justpy

I am getting this error for days now . Tried to downgrade from Python3.9.9 to Python3.9.2 for setuptools - demsjon - justpy compatibility reasons. I am trying to convert JavaScript into a Python dict. It's a Spline diagram that I want to make on a Quasar page.

Here is the code :

```
import justpy as jp

chart_def = """
{
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        inverted: true
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Atmosphere Temperature by Altitude'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'According to the Standard Atmosphere Model'
    },
    xAxis: {
        reversed: false,
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Altitude'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} km'
        },
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: 0 to 80 km.'
        },
        maxPadding: 0.05,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°'
        },
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: -90°C to 20°C.'
        },
        lineWidth: 2
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x} km: {point.y}°C'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enable: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: [[0, 15], [10, -50], [20, -56.5], [30, -46.5], [40, -22.1],
            [50, -2.5], [60, -27.7], [70, -55.7], [80, -76.5]]
    }]
}
"""

def app():
    wp = jp.WebPage()
    my_chart = jp.HighCharts(
        a=wp, classes='m-2 p-2 border', style='width: 600px')
    my_chart.options = chart_def
    return wp

jp.justpy(app)
```

I get a huuuuge traceback message:

```
JustPy ready to go on http://127.0.0.1:8000
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
....
..
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
ERROR h11_impl: Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
...
..
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
..
..
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
ERROR h11_impl: Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
..
..

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Update:

I managed to get past this error and I'm getting a new one using demjson==2.2.4:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Fotis Avg\Desktop\Python_course\DataAnalysis3rdApp\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import justpy as jp
  File "C:\Users\Fotis Avg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\justpy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>       
    from .justpy import *
  File "C:\Users\Fotis Avg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\justpy\justpy.py", line 13, in <module>        
    from .chartcomponents import *
  File "C:\Users\Fotis Avg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\justpy\chartcomponents.py", line 2, in <module>
    import demjson
  File "C:\Users\Fotis Avg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\demjson.py", line 645
    class json_int( (1L).__class__ ):    # Have to specify base this way to satisfy 2to3
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: There is no problem in your code, can you post the exact error?look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727149/dict-object-has-no-attribute-has-key

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I checked the post but it doesn't help me much because i think the problem is within demjson . 
I don't have has_key() inside my code to chance it to a new format

Comment: I think it's a module 'demjson.py' written in python 2.x, for this you need to translate your code into 3.x look at this page: https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson/issues/29

Comment: I run 2to3 on dmjson.py . Turn out it was not automatically transalted to python3.x
Thank you very much !!