# Django deepcopy object with foreign keys

Tags: python, django, postgresql

A usual copy of a certain object of `class A` in Django would look like this:

```
obj = A.objects.get(...) # get the object
obj.id = None
obj.save()
```

However if `class A` has a foreign key of some `class B` than the copy will reference the same object as the initial object, which will break constraints sometimes.

How can I make django recursively duplicate all the referenced objects as well?

I suppose it would look something like this:

```
def duplicate(obj):
   obj.id = None
   obj.save()
   refs = ? # somehow get the inner objects which are foreign keys       
   for inner_obj in refs:
      duplucate(inner_obj)

obj = A.objects.get(...) # get the object
duplicate(obj)
```

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234986/duplicate-django-model-instance-and-all-foreign-keys-pointing-to-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate Django Model Instance and All Foreign Keys Pointing to It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234986/duplicate-django-model-instance-and-all-foreign-keys-pointing-to-it)